# join 3 sql tables and make nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

So I have 3 tables called `comments`, `users` and `posts`.
I want to get

1. the "score" from comments
2. the "user reputation" for users by doing the left join between comments and users with c.user_id = u.id
3. get the "tags" from posts table by doing a left join between comments and posts on c.post_id = p.id.

   BUT there is a trick here the tags should be based on the type of the posts (p.post_type_id).

   So if the id = 1 then that means we have a "question" as a post and simply retrieve tag

   Else if the id = 2 then that means we have an answer and to get the tag we have to look at its parent_id from posts table.

I tried to use WHERE, CASE, nested IF, and nested SELECT but all threw syntax errors

Finally, I tried to do the following but I got an empty result

```
SELECT c.score, 
    COALESCE (u.reputation) reputation,
    COALESCE (p.tags) tags
FROM comments c 
    LEFT JOIN users u 
        ON c.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN posts p 
        ON (c.post_id = p.id AND p.post_type_id = 1) OR (c.post_id = p.id AND p.post_type_id = 2 )
             WHERE (p.id = p.parent_id)
```

So how can I have the tags based on the two types ?

Comment: Are you using Postgres or MySQL?  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Just quick guess:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1cc3/1

```
SELECT c.score, 
    u.reputation reputation,
    IF(p.post_type_id=1,p.tags,
                 IF(p.post_type_id=2,parents.tags,'UNKNOWN POST TYPE')
       ) tags
FROM comments c 
    LEFT JOIN users u 
        ON c.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN posts p 
        ON c.post_id = p.id  
    LEFT JOIN posts parents 
       ON parents.id = p.parent_id
```

**UPDATE** Here is Postgres variant:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a1cc3/2

```
SELECT c.score, 
    u.reputation,
    CASE p.post_type_id 
         WHEN 1 THEN p.tags
         WHEN 2 THEN parents.tags
         ELSE 'UNKNOWN POST TYPE'
    END tags
FROM comments c 
LEFT JOIN users u 
   ON c.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN posts p 
   ON c.post_id = p.id  
LEFT JOIN posts parents 
   ON parents.id = p.parent_id
```

Comment: here what I got:                                                                                      ERROR:  function if(boolean, text, unknown) does not exist
LINE 4:                  IF(p.post_type_id=2,parents.tags,'UNKNOWN P...
                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function if(boolean, text, unknown) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 96

Comment: @akalthubaity **function does not exist** probably you have no mysql installed :-) what exact server do you use: **MSSQL? MySQL? Postgres SQL?**

Comment: Alex I fixed that typo :) but still got the same error.. I am using postgresql